# How to get equal size cells when using rasterize in QGIS on slanted points

Tags: qgis, raster, point, rasterization, raster-conversion

I'm trying to get nice, centered cells on every point. I'm using the tool rasterize in QGIS. I have gotten the method to work with uniform point data, however, I am having more trouble with slanted point data. Here is the method I generally use in the extent to get my desired results:

- take xmin, subtract half of the width
- take xmin, subtract half of the width
- take ymin, subtract half of height
- take ymax, add half of the height

Here is a photo of what happens when I use the same method on slanted points:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas of any slight changes that may have to be made to make this work?

Comment: Are both layers in the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, both the raster and points are the same CRS.